# Clicking particular class name on webpage doesn't work JAVASCRIPT CHROME EXTENSION

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on chrome extension. In one of my files (content script) I want to remotely click a particular element of a particular webpage. I know class names [names showed in img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opXZC.png) of elements that I would like to be clicked.

Unluckily any options doesn't like clean JS or jQuery work for me (but 2 days ago it worked and I didn't change the method!). I know that content script is on the page I want, because of the console.log. My content script content (yeah desperately I try every option to show that it doesn't work at all, even one single options of those underneath is not working).

```
let check = location.href;
if (check.includes("categories")){

   try {
     console.log("works");
     $(document).on('click', '.styles__Label-causv5-1 giszo', function() {
       alert('hello');
        });
     document.getElementsByClassName('.articleButton___wrapper___3GdN_ core___flip-container___11Bqu').click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('.styles__Label-causv5-1 giszo').click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('.sc-AxmLO egaafL auto-tests-add-to-cart-button articleButton___add-to-cart___1Nngf core___flipper___3yDf4').click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('articleButton___wrapper___3GdN_ core___flip-container___11Bqu').click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Label-causv5-1 giszo').click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('sc-AxmLO egaafL auto-tests-add-to-cart-button articleButton___add-to-cart___1Nngf core___flipper___3yDf4').click();

     $('.styles__Wrapper-causv5-0 eBUpQR auto-tests-add-to-cart-button articleButton___add-to-cart___1Nngf core___flipper___3yDf4').click(function() { });
     $('.styles__Label-causv5-1 giszo').click();

     // yeah there is catch{} and other stuff under it but it doesn't matter here
```

Comment: those classnames are dynamically generated and will change every time

Comment: When I inspect the page they have the same name, even when i check other pages with different stuff, they have an equal name. So I don't get it